# How to access the contents that are created by custom content type using module

Tags: 7, nodes

I am new to drupal, I wished to view the contents using custom modules. For that, I have created custom content type and added some contents. Now I want to create a module to display all the contents that are created by those content types, in a page. Contents should have title, image, description, date field. How can I do that.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) to list content of custom content type.

Update(Programmatically load nodes):

```
<?php
$type = "custom_content_type";
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
foreach($nodes as $node):
?>
<?php print $node->nid; ?>
<?php print $node->title; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Ref: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_load_multiple/7

Comment: I have already tried that and got succeeded. But, now I wished to bring all those contents using my custom module. So, how can I do.?

Comment: You can use `node_load_multiple` function to list all nodes of custom content type. See updated answer

Comment: @karthik you won't find someone to write your code for you here, it's too broad of a request and would only be useful to you, not future visitors. have a look at the module developers guide on Drupal.org and ask a specific question when you get stuck